# Program crashing when i use the frament shader on another pc

Tags: c++, fragment-shader

It's my shader file

```
#version 430 core

flat in vec4 gColor;
in vec4 gTexCoord;
in vec4 gVertexPosition;
layout (location = 40) uniform sampler2D texture0;
layout (location = 41) uniform sampler2D texture1;
layout (location = 42) uniform int UseTexture;
layout (location = 43) uniform int UseClippingX;
layout (location = 44) uniform int UseClippingY;
layout (location = 45) uniform int UseClippingZ;
layout (location = 46) uniform vec3 Depth_of_view;
layout (location = 47) uniform vec3 Height_of_intersection;


out vec4 FragColor;

void main(void)
{
    if (UseTexture == 1)
    {
        vec4 texColor0 = texture2D(texture0, vec2(gTexCoord.x, gTexCoord.y));
        vec4 texColor1 = texture2D(texture1, gTexCoord.xy);
        FragColor = texColor0 + gColor;
        return;
    }

    if( (UseClippingX == 1) && ((gVertexPosition.x > Height_of_intersection.x) || (gVertexPosition.x < Depth_of_view.x)) )
        discard;
    if( (UseClippingY == 1) && ((gVertexPosition.y > Height_of_intersection.y) || (gVertexPosition.y < Depth_of_view.y)) )
        discard;
    if( (UseClippingZ == 1) && ((gVertexPosition.z > Height_of_intersection.z) || (gVertexPosition.z < Depth_of_view.z)) )
        discard;

    FragColor = gColor;
}
```

and when i check this with if function program crash.

```
shader_1_frag = new QOpenGLShader(QOpenGLShader::Fragment);
if (!shader_1_frag->compileSourceFile(":/shaders/shader_1.frag"))
    QMessageBox::critical(this, "Shader compiler", "Fragment shader failed to compile!");
```

I dont know the where is the problem?

Note: I'm trying compile the another PC and its using Intel HD Graphics Family

Comment: You should check the error string using [`QOpenGLShader::log`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglshader.html#log).  It's possible the OpenGL/GLSL version requested isn't supported.

Comment: I'm sharing my OpenGL details:

Renderer: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400
Vendor: Intel
Version: 4.3.0 - Build 20.19.15.5063
Shading language version: 4.30 - Build 20.19.15.5063

Comment: W (0x42e2c658|19372) QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): ERROR: 3:36: 'texture2D' : function is removed in Forward Compatible context 
ERROR: 3:36: 'texture2D' : function is removed in Forward Compatible context 
ERROR: 3:35: '=' :  cannot convert from 'const highp float' to '4-component vector of highp float'
ERROR: 3:37: 'texture2D' : function is removed in Forward Compatible context 
ERROR: 3:37: 'texture2D' : function is removed in Forward Compatible context 
ERROR: 3:36: '=' :  cannot convert from 'const highp float' to '4-component vector of highp float'

Comment: #if __VERSION__ > 120
    color = texture(sampler, texCoord);
#else
    color = texture2D(sampler, texCoord);
#endif

It's works but i cant see my graphics on my program.